# CSS full width horizontal scroll

Tags: html, css, scroll, width

I have just completed the following [website](http://dev.jzm.co.nz/) but when I load it I seem to have an excess scroll.

Could you please give me feedback as to why and how could I resolve this issue.

I can post the code here but most people from the previous questions I have had over the last couple of days like a working example

Comment: it's your `.footer nav`.

Comment: Yup. Instead of reducing the width of that NAV element, you've set a negative right margin. \*facepalm\* `:)`

Comment: About posting code on your question: it's highly recommended indeed. If possible, adding a working example is also very helpful. Both posted code and the working example should not be your full code, but rather the shortest example that reproduces the issue (see http://sscce.org/). Many times, the process of preparing this example will lead you to find the root cause of your issue.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas im now thinking wtf add that as a answer

Comment: @bfavaretto Will you provide the answer, or should I do it?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, go for it! You have my blessing `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the NAV element in the footer had a negative right margin, which caused a horizontal overflow, which in turn caused the scroll-bar to appear. I guess, your intention was to move the nav-items further to the right.

To get rid of the scroll-bar, just remove the negative margin, and instead set the width of the NAV to the appropriate value.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add following line to your wrapper

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this css property to your `<div id="wrapper">` element:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) for the official documentation of the overflow-x property.

Your css should look something like this:

```
#wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     min-height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

I've tried it in Safari(version 5.1.7), Firefox(11.x) and Google Chrome(19.x) on a Mac Os and it works like a charm.

Hope it helps!